# tkinter, not able to insert text in a text widget in some circumstances

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget

Im writing tkinter program to control a model railway.  Im having trouble inserting text into a text widget, which I want to use to inform the operator what is happening.  The following code is a simple program I wrote to illustrate the problem Im having.  When I click the 'Write text' button the two print statements and the while true loop in the write_to_txtwidget function all work. BUT the insert command does not send text to the text widget.  If I delete the while true loop, the text is inserted as expected in the text widget.

The problems appears to be due to the while true loop, but I don't understand why the insert command is not executed before the program enters the loop.  Any advice would be appreciated the

```
#tkinter import
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

#Define and configure root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200+250+200') #(Root width x root height + Horizontal posn + Vertical posn)
root.title('Txt widgit')
root.resizable(0,0)

#Define and configure text boxes
textwidget = tk.Text(root, wrap='word', height=4, width=21, bg = 'palegreen')
textwidget.grid(column=0,row=2)

#Define and configure buttons
button = tk.Button(root, text='Write text', height=1, width = 16, command = lambda:write_to_txtwidgit())
button.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky=tk.W)

# Proceedures
def write_to_txtwidgit():
    print('Text 1 from print command')
    textwidget.delete('1.0','end')
    textwidget.insert('1.0','Text to be sent to text widget')
    print('Text 2 from print command')
    while True:
        print('printing from while true statement')
        sleep(1)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just call `root.update()` before the loop :)

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  That works just as I wanted.  Ive spent hours searching the web for the answer with no luck!  Thanks again, Graham

Comment: You're welcome, no worries! In your defense, tkinter is sadly pretty unintuitive

Comment: Thanks for the get out clause! Putting the update command in the actual program now and its working great!